# Open a specific Excel document, then go to a specific cell

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to create a simple VBA script that will open a specific Excel document, then go to a specific cell. The current code will work every other time. I have searched and found several topics and threads but nothing that has resolved the issue.

Here is the code that I am using.

```
Dim oApp As Object    
Dim oSheet As Object  

Set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oApp.Visible = True
oApp.Workbooks.Open "path to excel documents" & [CopperMap]

Set oSheet = oApp.Worksheets([SpreadSheet])

oSheet.Activate

ActiveCell.Activate
Range([CellColumn]).Activate
```

CopperMap, SpreadSheet, and CellColumn are columns in my table that have the required information.

Comment: The code should work. Check the data from table you use in parameters under debugger, quite sure that the problem is there. Or temporary replace parameters by string constants with file name, worksheet and cell reference.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it isn't working all the time (not sure why you're activating the active cell - it's already active).

I've never had problems with the code below (commented out code is optional):

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWrkBk As Object
    Dim oWrkSht As Object
    Dim oRng As Object

    Set oXL = CreateXL
    Set oWrkBk = oXL.workbooks.Open("<path and workbook name>.xlsx")
    Set oWrkSht = oWrkBk.Worksheets("<sheet name>")
    Set oRng = oWrkSht.range("A1")

    'Select the range.
        'oWrkSht.select
        'oRng.select

    'Go to the range.
        'oXL.Goto Reference:=oWrkSht.range("A1"), Scroll:=True

    'Do stuff with the range (no need to select it).
    oRng.Value = "10"
    MsgBox oRng.Address & " has the value of " & oRng.Value

End Sub

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Before I added "ActiveCell.Activate" The code would just open up the appropriate excel document and go to the proper sheet but it would not do anything with the cell and gave me a different error code. Once I used the ActiveCell syntax, it began to work (every other time).

When it debugs, it highlights the ActiveCell.Activate line.

When I get into work in the morning, i will give your code a try!

Answer (score 0):

Darren,

Thank you for the suggestion. I actually ended up solving this with my own code. I found that, while in debugging mode, the script would work perfectly after I hit the stop button after each try. I then found the syntax of "End" which stops all macros. This ended up solving the issue since now I can run the script with no issues after putting "End" at the end of my script.